# I am trying to insert multiple values from the select drop down using PHP, but it's only taking the last value selected

Tags: php

I have tried using the implode and foreach function, but still it's taking the last selected value.

This is the php insertion code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $research = $_POST['research'];
    $reg = $_POST['RegNo'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $staff = $_POST['staff'];

    foreach ($staff as $choice) {
        require 'connectdb.php';
        $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO research ( Name, Topic, Year, RegNo, staffID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);');
        $statement->bind_param('sssss', $researchh, $topicc, $yearr, $regg, $stafff);
        $researchh = $research;
        $topicc = $topic;
        $yearr = $year;
        $regg = $reg;
        $stafff = $choice;
    }

    if ($statement->execute() == false) {
        if ($conn->errno === 1062) {
            header('Location:?exists');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location:?newstudentTopic');
    }

}
?>
```

This is the form field:

```
<div class="col-md-6">

    <label for="gender">Supervior</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker border border-info" id="staff" required name="staff[]"
            data-live-search="true" multiple data-max-options="2" multiple="multiple">

        <option value=""> Allocate Supervisor</option>

        <?php
        require 'connectdb.php';
        $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT staffid,fname,lname from staff');
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->bind_result($staffid, $fname, $lname);
        $statement->store_result();
        while ($statement->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $staffid ?>"><?php echo $fname . ' ' . $lname ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        $statement->close();
        $conn->close();
        ?>
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The execute command is outside the loop, also do not include the 'connectdb.php' inside the loop or use require_once.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to `prepare` the sql once and then `execute` multiple times ~ that's part of the beauty of the `prepared statement` style.

You ought to test that the required fields are available within the POST array - below I created an array of fields to test ~ the first test determines if any of the required fields are empty and the second determines if someone is trying to inject other parameters in to the POST array.

You should include `require` the database connection ONCE and not within the loop.

Finally just loop through the array of `staff` and execute the query for each iteration.

```
<?php 
    try{
        $results=[];
        $fields=['research','RegNo','topic','year','staff','register'];

        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
            if( empty( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) {
                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Missing field "%s"', $field ) );
            }
        }

        foreach( $_POST as $field ){
            if( !in_array( $field, $fields ) ) {
                throw new Exception( sprintf('Unknown field "%s"', $field ) );
            }
        }
        /* include the db connection once, NOT in the loop */
        require 'connectdb.php';

        $research=$_POST['research'];
        $reg=$_POST['RegNo'];
        $topic=$_POST['topic'];
        $year=$_POST['year'];
        /* this is a multiple field - array */
        $arr_staff=$_POST['staff'];

        /* Create the sql statement once - NOT in the loop */
        $sql='INSERT INTO research ( `Name`, `Topic`, `Year`, `RegNo`, `staffID`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);'
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

        if( !$stmt )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare SQL');
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $research, $topic, $year, $reg, $staff );


        foreach( $arr_staff as $staff ){
            $results[]=$stmt->execute();
        }

        exit( header( 'Location: ?newstudentTopic' ) );

    } catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple glitches in your code. I have optimized it a bit and fixed the issue pertaining to your needs. please let me know if it works.

I have tried using the implode and foreach function, but still it's taking the last selected value.

This is the php insertion code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
require 'connectdb.php';

$research = $_POST['research'];
$reg = $_POST['RegNo'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$staff = $_POST['staff'];
$isSuccess = 1;
foreach ($staff as $choice) {
    $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO research ( Name, Topic, Year, RegNo, staffID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);');
    $statement->bind_param('sssss', $researchh, $topicc, $yearr, $regg, $stafff);
    $researchh = $research;
    $topicc = $topic;
    $yearr = $year;
    $regg = $reg;
    $stafff = $choice;
    if ($statement->execute() == false) {
       $isSuccess = 0;
    }
}


    if (!$isSuccess) {
        header('Location:?exists');
    }
    else {
    header('Location:?newstudentTopic');
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Place your `$statement->execute()` within your `foreach` loop and you are good to go :)

You could do it like this:

```
// needs to be included only once
require 'connectdb.php';

// you can use this multiple times
$statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO research ( Name, Topic, Year, RegNo, staffID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);');

$success = true;
foreach ($staff as $choice) {
    $researchh = $research;
    $topicc = $topic;
    $yearr = $year;
    $regg = $reg;
    $stafff = $choice;

    $statement->bind_param('sssss', $researchh, $topicc, $yearr, $regg, $stafff);

    $success = $statement->execute() && $success;

    // Do this if you want to stop inserting after one fails
    // if($success === false) {
    //     break;
    // }
}

if ($success) {
    header('Location:?exists');
} else {
    header('Location:?newstudentTopic');
}
exit; // thx @halfer :)
```

In case you want to insert only if there is not a single execute failing have a look at transactions: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: Also, the `header()` Location statements should be immediately followed by an exit, so the script does not attempt to carry on afterwards.